# Como pegar a data de amanha com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Olá.

Tenho esse código:

```js
var datas = new Date();
console.log(datas.toLocaleDateString());
```

Ele me retorna: 22/05/2017

Tem como fazer com que ele retorne sempre com um dia a mais? assim: 23/05/2017

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assim:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
```